# Adjuntar (Renderizar) texto a un Drawable en Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

He hecho algo de investigación en la red y encontré esta clase aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972445/how-to-put-text-in-a-drawable

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;

    public TextDrawable(String text) {
            this.text = text;

            this.paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setTextSize(24f);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
            paint.setShadowLayer(6f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
            paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
            paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        }
    }
```

El `drawable` es un `<layer-list>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/backgroundColor" />

    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/imagen1" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

He intentado lo sigiente:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextDrawable textDrawable = new TextDrawable(" ** Bienvenido ** ");

    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layerdraw, null);

    ld.mutate();

    ld.addLayer(textDrawable);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);

}
```

Pero el texto no aparece. Si hay un método mejor, es bienvenido.

NÓTESE que estoy desplegando dicho `drawable` como el background temporalmente, pero podría ser también dentro de un `ImageWiew`.

**Edición**

He investigado un poco más y he descubierto que probablemente no sea posible hacerlo directamente con el `layer-list`, sin embargo, he visto que es SI posible hacerlo conviertiendo dicho layer-list en un bitmap y entonces superponerle el texto, ¿cómo hago esto? ¿Cómo convierto este drawable a bitmap?. En todo caso contaría como solución a esta pregunta, pues solo quiero que el texto quede en conjunto como imagen de fondo.

Comment: Tu clase TextDrawable debe funcionar solo verifica las coordenadas donde deseas desplegar la imagen y asegura que no tenga wrap_content como alto y ancho el ImageView contenedor, agregue una respuesta, comenta resultados. @Chipkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el método que usas mediante `canvas.drawText()` se puede realizar sin problema, el `ImageView` donde se "renderizara" el texto, no debe tener propiedades `wrap_content`, podrías asignar `match_parent`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

y toma en cuenta en donde vas a dibujar el texto, por default el ejemplo que muestras, se mostraría en la esquina superior izquierda, coordenadas 0,0 en Android.

```
canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
```

estas dos pueden ser las causas por las cuales no se muestra el texto.

---

Comparto mi clase **TextDrawable** la cual para instanciar necesita del contexto, el texto a desplegar, posicion X y posición Y, el tamaño del texto lo puedes configurar dentro de la clase mediante la variable `FONT_SIZE`.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

    public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

        private final String text;
        private final Paint paint;
        private float positionx = 0;
        private float positiony = 0;
        private Context ctx;
        private static final float FONT_SIZE = 24.0f;

        public TextDrawable(Context ctx, String text, int positionx, int positiony) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.text = text;
            this.positionx = positionx;
            this.positiony = positiony;
            this.paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            paint.setTextSize(getPxfromDP(FONT_SIZE));

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
            paint.setShadowLayer(8f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);//align center
        }

        //Convert Pixels to Dp
        private float getPxfromDP(float dpValue) {
            float density = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            return dpValue * density + 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawText(text, getPxfromDP(positionx), getPxfromDP(positiony), paint);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
            paint.setColorFilter(cf);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        }
    }
```

Como ejemplo de uso

```
TextDrawable textDrawable = new TextDrawable(getApplicationContext(), "Elenasys was here!", 200, 200);
myImageView.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
```

para obtener este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto, el problema era el tamaño de la fuente y la posición en la que necesitaba desplegarse el texto en el contenedor, el cálculo tomando en cuenta la DPI funciona de maravilla.